# Error while running Glassfish Server 3:"Server cannot operate in current Locale. Locale switched to en_US for the processs."

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

i wrote basic EJB project(hello world) at netbeans 6.9.1
when i try to deploy project with glassfish, its gives "Server cannot operate in current Locale. Locale switched to en_US for the processs." error and say "GlassFish Server 3 Start Failed".
how can i fix this problem

Comment: File a bug against serverplugins/GlassFish v3 in the NetBeans issue tracker and I will look at it there. http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi.

Comment: i filed the bug, hope you can fix my bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem and fixed it. The cause was another program using port 8080. When I closed that program, Glassfish Server 3 started working fine. If someone has the same problem, I hope this will be helpfull.